# Relative imports: subpackage importing subpackage

Tags: python, python-import, relative-path

Directory structure:

```
root/
   script.py
   package/
      __init__.py
      module1.py
      module2.py
```

In `script.py` I need to import a method from `module1.py` and run it.

```
#contents of script.py 
from package.module1 import func1

func1()
```

The method in `module1.py` requires a method from `module2.py`.

```
#contents of module1.py 
from package.module2 import func2

def func1():
    func2()

if __name__ == "__main__":
     func1()
```

---

The above code works if I run `script.py` directly. There are some situations, however, where I need to run `module1.py` directly via `crontab` and this is where the problem lies.

When the cronjob runs, I get an error saying `func2` can't be found. I can run `module1.py` if I modify the import to the following:

```
#contents of module1.py 
from module2 import func2

def func1():
    func2()

if __name__ == "__main__":
     func1()
```

I can make both situations work if I add an `else` statement in `module1.py` but it looks so hacky:

```
#contents of module1.py 

def func1():
    func2()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from module2 import func2 
    func1()
else:
    from package.module2 import func2
    func1()
```

How can I do this more pythonically? Maybe I need to utilize `__init__.py` somehow? It's just an empty file at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running a file with `python file.py` python does *not* look at the directory containing `file` for `__init__.py`. This means you cannot use `import package.module` nor `from .module import x` imports.

The way to fix this is to tell python that `file.py` is part of a package. This is done by using the `-m` switch:

```
python -m package.module1
```

So you don't have to fix your code, you have to fix your `crontab` command!

---

This said: I personally never like to run modules. I'd rather write a `run_module1.py` script outside the package that simply contains:

```
from package import module1
module1.func1()
```

Then run `run_module1.py` instead of running `module1.py` directly.

I don't think there is any good reason to want to run `module1.py` as you are doing and expecting it to work without hacky imports as you tried. AFAIK there is no non-hackish solution to that.

Comment: Hmm so I'm having same issue if in my crontab I run `python -m package.module1` and `module1.py` imports `func2` with the following `from package.module2 import func2`. How does the `-m` switch resolve the issue with the fact that when I run `script.py` I'm in `root`, but running `module1.py` I'm in `root/package`?

Comment: @user1964692 You will have to edit your question and add how you are defining the `crontab` command. Some sensible commands could be `cd /path/to/parent && python -m package.module1`, or you can install your package and just do `python -m package.module1`, or you could run `PYTHONPATH=/path/to/parent python -m package.module1` where `/path/to/parent` is the parent directory of `package` (so you have `/path/to/parent/package/module1.py`)